# <asynchronous suspension> in stacktrace output in flutter

Tags: flutter

I use the Log package for logging which also outputs the stacktrace.

Between my log message I see `<asynchronous suspension>` a lot of times. Can someone tell me what it means?

Comment: `<asynchronous suspension>` is not an indication of a problem, it just indicates that code execution is not synchronous code executed line-by-line, but instead a callback from a completed Future started at some position in the callstack.

Comment: I think you could post this as the anwser.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`<asynchronous suspension>` is not an indication of a problem, it just indicates that code execution is not synchronous code executed line-by-line, but instead a callback from a completed Future started at some position in the callstack

Comment: Sometimes internet is not connected then this type of error occurs in API

Answer (score 1):

If Code and everything is okay, Check your Internet connection, check emulator internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

This error may occur if you have added a splash screen with flutter_native_splash and deleted **flutter_native_splash.yaml** to remove the splash screen.

Try the following to get rid of this issue:

1. Go to **android\app\src\main\res\drawable** and do following changes.

**Delete this:**

```
<item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
</item>
```

**and add this one line of code:**

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

2. Delete **background.png** from this directory.

Do the same thing for **android\app\src\main\res\drawable-v21**.

I hope it helps.