# <asynchronous suspension> Error in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am new to flutter and I dont know how to go about this. Any help will be appreciated!

```
E/flutter ( 6560): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6560): 
E/flutter ( 6560): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6560): Receiver: null
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658945/asynchronous-suspension-in-stacktrace-output-in-flutter

Comment: [Mohammed Abdallah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15029896) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209174) saying "can you show me the code. it might be in the declaration you should make the list = [];"

Answer (score 0):

The error simply states that the operator `[]` is called on a variable that does not contain a Map object and is rather `null`. Common workaround for this is to place a check for `null` or provide a default value for map using `??` every time before you access a property of map.

You can do something like create a private method:

```
getValue(String key) {return map != null ? map[key] : null;}
```

And use this method in whole widget to access values from Map.

If this is not the case, try to provide [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So that everyone could check what might causing you this error.