# synchronous suspension in flutter Google Signin (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm trying to integrate Google-SignIn Firebase into my app, But I'm getting this error. I have already done this a couple of times with no problem. but this time. I checked all other discussions please don't refer me to them. thank you.... I checked this discussion but no solution ([<asynchronous suspension> in stacktrace output in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658945/asynchronous-suspension-in-stacktrace-output-in-flutter))

Error :

```
E/flutter ( 5639): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter ( 5639): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5639): #1      GoogleSignIn._callMethod
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:231
E/flutter ( 5639): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5639): #2      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart)
package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:1
E/flutter ( 5639): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5639):





class AuthServices {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    // Obtain the auth details from the request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    // Create a new credential
    final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final User user = userCredential.user;
    final userData = {
      'name': googleUser.displayName,
      'email': googleUser.email,
      'id': googleUser.id,
      'photo': googleUser.photoUrl,
    };

    users.doc(user.uid).get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          users.doc(user.uid).update(userData);
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        } else {
          // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
          users.doc(user.uid).set(userData);
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Signup()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- make sure you added the SHA1 keys

2- make sure you added google play services

3- (**I think this is you problem**) you have to add the support email in firebase console like this.

go to your firebase project setting -> general tab -> Public settings -> support email then add it and reinstall the app

[image]

4- try updating the **OAuth consent screen** on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

[image]

Comment: Hey, man. Yes. I always check them. both are there. Actually, i used my snippet so no problem with the code probably.  it's 2 days couldn't find the solution.

Comment: go to your firebase project setting -> general tab -> Public settings -> support email then add it

and reinstall the app

Comment: also make sure you enabled google signing in firebase -> authentication -> signing methods

Comment: try updating the OAuth consent screen on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: Thank you, bro. couldn't find the email support. should I add that?

Comment: if it worked no need but you cant still find it in 
firebase project setting -> general tab -> Public settings -> support email dropdown

Comment: and if the previous steps solved your project please accept the question "mark it as answered"