# showModalBottomSheet: show dialog before bottom sheet close

Tags: flutter

I want to show the user a bottom sheet to edit some values.
I display a save button once a TextField is changed that writes to the database.
Writing to the database on every edit would be very slow as I need to serialize the data too.

I want to display a warning dialog if the bottom sheet is closed without the user having saved the edited data.
The bottom sheet should only close if the user is sure that their edits can be lost.

I found that Flutter's [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) already has an [onClosing](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet/onClosing.html) callback. However, I didn't find any way to configure (set) it from [showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html), therefore the question.

The docs say that by using `showModalBottomSheet`, `BottomSheet` becomes the parent of the widget returned by `builder`. However, as far as I know, there is no way for a widget to access it's parent widget in Flutter.

**This is NOT a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556037/showmodalbottomsheet-function-onclose). That wants a way to do stuff *after* the sheet was closed. I want to do this *before* the sheet gets closed**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WillPopScope` Widget to wrap the contents of your `showModalBottomSheet`. When the user tries to close the modal the WillPopScope is triggered and there you can add a condition in order to check if the modalBottomSheet should actually close or not. For example, there you can trigger an AlertDialog that informs the user about potential data loss and  let him decide between two options.

An example of this AlertDialog could be:

> If you continue you will lose all edited data. Are you sure that you
> want to proceed?
>
> CTA: 'Yes', 'No'

If user selects 'Yes' then you can return WillPopScope true and your modal will be dismissed. If the user selects 'No', then the WillPopScope will return false and the bottomModalSheet won't pop.

Here is an example with WillPopScope https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html

There is a known issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106942) though that WillPopScope doesn't work when user drags the modalbottomsheet in order to dismiss it. That means that you have to set `enableDrag` to `false`.